# "AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package" error

Tags: android

This may be more of a Linux bug than a programming error, but I am not sure. The AndroidManifest.xml is somewhat Greek to me. That said, my program has compiled and run before in it's current state perfectly fine, it is even on the Market. Its been around a month since I've opened the source in Eclipse, and today when I opened it, it refused to compile and displays the following errors:

```
[2010-12-10 10:43:19 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read /media/DATA/code/Android/XXX/AndroidManifest.xml: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/XXX/AndroidManifest.xml'.

[2010-12-10 10:43:19 - XXX] AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted.
```

where XXX is the package name (and directory it is located). I have confirmed that the file is perfectly fine in a text editor, and even refreshed it in Eclipse. Nothing.

I updated the ADT...maybe the criteria for AndroidManifest.xml changed?

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.XXX.XXX"
 android:versionCode="2"
 android:versionName="1.0.1"
 >

 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

     <activity 
      android:name=".XXX"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"

   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
   >

   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

  <activity 
   android:name=".FindLocationsActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   >
  </activity>

  <activity 
   android:name=".DeveloperActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >
  </activity>

  <activity 
   android:name=".LegalActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >
  </activity>

  <activity 
   android:name=".AboutActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  >
  </activity>

  <activity 
   android:name=".SettingsAndAboutActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   >
  </activity>

  <activity
   android:name=".ResultsPageActivity"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   >
  </activity>

    </application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="1" 
/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Refreshing project/files does NOT solve the problem...

Answer (score 21):

This exception is not Android related:

> [2010-12-10 10:43:19 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read /media/DATA/code/Android/XXX/AndroidManifest.xml: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/XXX/AndroidManifest.xml'.

It means the file that is loaded in the Eclipse editor is not the same as the one on the filesystem.

Click the resource (or even better, the eclipse project) in the navigator or package explorer view, right click and select 'Refresh.'

Whether or not this will completely fix your build issue won't be known until you see what the file *actually* contains.

Comment: beat me to the punch by 50 seconds ;)

Answer (score 12):

This error occurs when you edit a workbench resource outside of Eclipse.
To fix this problem, right click the project or edited resource and select “Refresh”.
If you edit outside of Eclipse a lot, you can enable auto-refresh by going to Window->Preferences menu, then in the Preferences dialog box, select General > Workspace.
Check the “Refresh automatically” box.

Comment: I had the same error and refreshing the entire project solved it for me. Try it again not with [F5] but with the right-click-menu>refresh.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked for me. I started having that problem when I began compiling my AndroidManifest.xml (to set an API key that changes between dev / staging and production) in a pre-compile step. The project auto-refresh preference solved my problem. Thanks @SRM

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse, if you encounter this issue, there are two common approaches to possibly resolve it.

1. Select the "Refresh" project just mentioned in other provided answers. (Right click on the project, and then select "Refresh".)
2. If the "Refresh" does not work, then try to "Clean" the project. (From the menu bar, select "Project" and then select the "Clean..." item. Make sure that you check the current project to clean.)

Normally, these two steps will resolve 90% of the compilation issues -- if the compilation error is not a direct result of some code changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem and refreshing the project worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error is eclipse when you are trying to import an AndroidStudio based project into your eclipse IDE.

If this is the case, there is no point in refreshing. You have to rearrange all the files from Java forlder to the src folder... (Its time to switch to Android Studio I guess)

Answer (score 0):

No answer worked for me. In my manifest file, attribute package was missing and hence it was giving this error.

I added this attribute using following code snippet and it worked after refreshing.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           package="com.example.myapp"  >
```