# Manifest file missing

Tags: android, xml, manifest

Is there a way to regenerate a manifest.xml file? For some reason when I closed my project in eclipse and re opened it it says the following:

**Resource /HTTPTabDemo/AndroidManifest.xml does not exist**

Will I have to create a new project and copy over files individually or is there a way I can fix it? I think it has something to do with me installing on device to test. Then closing project in IDE while leaving manifest open in tab bar then closing it.

Very annoying, any help much appreciated!

Comment: did you check on the file system if the thing is there? Quite often eclipse and sdk just get a bit lost and a good right click on the project tree->Refresh and then Project->Clean solves it.

Comment: Yes it displays in package explorer. when I try to open it then it displays the message above. I tried the refresh but no joy!

Comment: it almost seems to me that Eclipse is bugged and if you get a fresh copy of it would solve. Use your normal file explorer (windows) or Finder (Mac) to check the file is there and the code of it is there.

Comment: Just did that and file exists but after having opened it in notepad is only shows the following line `
    <manifest xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android package="com.example.tabdemo"></manifest>` I have a bad feeling I might have to start over!

Comment: apparently yes. Eclipse might be a real pain sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyways. I think something similar to the following post might have happened to me so for anyone with this issue read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411488/androidmanifest-xml-does-not-declare-a-java-package-error

Comment: You might be able to restore it from local history in eclipse

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, please accept it, otherwise post what worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

I had the same problem. I googled it, searched Stack Overflow for an answer, and nothing.
Then I tried to create another project, but I couldn't give it the name of my "bugged project" because it was still in the workspace. So misteriously, I renamed my "bugged project", and the error was gone!

For instance:

- Your project name is Proj1
- Rename it to Proj2
- Then, rename it again to Proj1

This worked for me.

Hope this helps