# AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted

Tags: android, eclipse

Getting this specific error over and over again, while building the project.

**AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package: Build aborted.**

Comment: paste AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project and select "Refresh" . or if this is not work "clean" the project and rebuild it again. see below link :
["AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411488/androidmanifest-xml-does-not-declare-a-java-package-error)

Comment: Thank you. Android Studio occasionally still has this issue. Cleaning the project remedies it.

Answer (score 1):

Does your manifest has package node? If no then add the package name to your manifest file like this

```
package="com.example.android"
```

othewise

see ["AndroidManifest.xml does not declare a Java package" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411488/androidmanifest-xml-does-not-declare-a-java-package-error/4411530) or http://forum.processing.org/one/topic/androidmanifest-xml-does-not-declare-a-java-package-build-aborted.html

Answer (score 0):

No answer worked for me. In my manifest file, attribute package was missing and hence it was giving this error.

I added this attribute using following code snippet and it worked after refreshing.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
           package="com.example.myapp"  >
```